# I am web scraping, trying to fetch a set of urls on a website page, however i am getting errors

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-science, data-mining

I am scraping this website for the urls however when i try to retrieve all of them, i keep getting errors
This is the source page with the urls
[![This is the source code of the page with the urls][1]][1]

I got the first url with this code

```
soup_bookstore.find('td' , style = "text-align: center;").a.get('href')
```

this was the result[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I then tried to retrieve the rest using this code

```
book_urls = [x.a.get('href') for x in soup_bookstore.find('td' , style = "text-align: center;")]

# Display number of fetched URLs
print(str(len(book_urls)) + " fetched book URLs")

# We can print all fetched URLS
for book in book_urls:
    print(book)
```

and i keep getting this error
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

My aim is to retrieve all the urls underneath each course name to put in a pandas dataframe
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtsUN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdYL.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PelX.png

Comment: Your post is essentially unreadable.  Eliminate all of the pictures and use text instead.

Comment: Some of the `td`’s do not contain an `a`, so you cannot call `x.a.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Since the details posted by you are not clear, based on @Vincent's comment

> Some of the td’s do not contain an a, so you cannot call x.a.get() – Vincent Bitter

**Try**

```
book_urls = [x.a.get('href') for x in soup_bookstore.find('td' , style = "text-align: center;") if x.a]
```

The `if` condition in the end checks whether the `td` has a child element `a` and enables accessing the `href` attribute only if `a` exists